# Proper Signature with HMAC operation phemex php header signature

Tags: php, curl, header, sha256

I found a sample github that is able to properly generate a signature for the API in question, their code is as follows:

so i found their github which has a sample in object oriented like this:

```
if ($api === 'private') {
$this->check_required_credentials();
$timestamp = $this->seconds();
$xPhemexRequestExpiry = $this->safe_integer($this->options, 'x-phemex-request-expiry', 60);
$expiry = $this->sum($timestamp, $xPhemexRequestExpiry);
$expiryString = (string) $expiry;
$headers = array(
'x-phemex-access-token' => $this->apiKey,
'x-phemex-request-expiry' => $expiryString,
);
$payload = '';
if ($method === 'POST') {
$payload = $this->json($params);
$body = $payload;
$headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
}
$auth = $requestPath . $queryString . $expiryString . $payload;
$headers['x-phemex-request-signature'] = $this->hmac($this->encode($auth), $this->encode($this->secret));
}
$url = $this->urls['api'][$api] . $url;
return array( 'url' => $url, 'method' => $method, 'body' => $body, 'headers' => $headers );
}
```

my code is core and looks like this, and I can not seem to get the proper result of a valid signature, any guidance possible?

```
 $epoch=strtotime(date('r', time()).'+2 days');
    $data = '{"clOrdId":"123456","ordType":"LIMIT","symbol":"BTC-USD","side":"BUY","orderQty":"0.1","price":"100"}';
    $content=("/orders".$epoch.$data);
    //SECRET KEY
    $str = 'cn87t3Z8wLw-OR626cuAZFIUhHT2z3XSfEt6X8OBSyFjU3Ny05ZWYyLTQ3ZjItODkwNy1mODlhNWMxM2UzMWY';
    $decode= base64_decode($str);
    $signature = hash_hmac('SHA256',$content,'$decode');
```

In short I need to send the signature inside the headers like so:

```
   "x-phemex-request-signature: $signature)",
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
$epoch=strtotime(date('r', time()).'+5 minutes');
$data = '{"clOrdId":"123456","ordType":"LIMIT","symbol":"BTC-USD","side":"BUY","orderQty":"0.1","price":"100"}';
$content="/orders".$epoch.$data;
//SECRET KEY
$str = 'cn87t3Z8wLw-OR626cuAZFIUhHT2z3XSfEt6X8OBSyFkMjE0NjU3Ny05ZWYyLTQ3ZjItODkwNy1mODlhNWMxM2UzMWY';
$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256',$auth,'cn87t3Z8wLw-OR626cuAZFIUhHT2z3XSfEt6X8OBSy***5ZWYyLTQ3ZjItODkwNy1mODlhNWMxM2UzMWY');
$headers = array(
   "accept: application/json",
   //API KEY
   "x-phemex-access-token:e92028ca-4704-4317-8149-c1c7a7f85226",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "x-phemex-request-expiry: $epoch",
   //this right here is what we need to have working proper
   "x-phemex-request-signature: $signature)",
   
);
```

The format of a proper signature looks like:

API REST Request URL: https://api.phemex.com/orders

```
Request Path: /orders
Request Query:
Request Body: {"symbol":"BTCUSD","clOrdID":"uuid-1573058952273","side":"Sell","priceEp":93185000,"orderQty":7,"ordType":"Limit","reduceOnly":false,"timeInForce":"GoodTillCancel","takeProfitEp":0,"stopLossEp":0}
Request Expiry: 1575735514
Signature: HMacSha256( /orders + 1575735514 + {"symbol":"BTCUSD","clOrdID":"uuid-1573058952273","side":"Sell","priceEp":93185000,"orderQty":7,"ordType":"Limit","reduceOnly":false,"timeInForce":"GoodTillCancel","takeProfitEp":0,"stopLossEp":0})
signed string is /orders1575735514{"symbol":"BTCUSD","clOrdID":"uuid-1573058952273","side":"Sell","priceEp":93185000,"orderQty":7,"ordType":"Limit","reduceOnly":false,"timeInForce":"GoodTillCancel","takeProfitEp":0,"stopLossEp":0}
```

Comment: php uses `.` for concatenation not `+`

Comment: also `'$decode'` is not the base64 value but a string `'$decode'`

Comment: i updated . instead of +.
Regarding decode it should be $signature = hash_hmac('SHA256',$content,'$str');?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I added updated code, and the goal they show as proper.